# arcmap buffer geoprocessing range error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, buffer

When I tried to create a buffer layer around a polyline layer. But I got the error as follows:

The input was outside a +-360 longitude range or outside +-90 latitude.

[image]

The input is : dev_db.DBO.Segment

The output is : D:\local\SegBuffer.shp

The buffer size : 10 meters

The error occurs regardless of the buffer size. Any hint on it?

I am using arcmap 10.2.2.

Comment: Could you give a little bit more information about the dataset you want to buffer? Is it a Shapefile or from a Geodatabase? My first guess would be that there is an issue with the coordinate system. Which coordinate system are you using?

Comment: Would you be able to copy/paste (or re-type) the precise error/warning message into your question as text, please? The picture is useful too but will not show up in a search.  Would you also be able to include the precise parameter values that you supplied to the buffer tool, please?

Comment: Hi Martin, I am buffering a Geodatabase layer. The coordinate system is GCS_SVY21.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn´t reproduce the error. What kind of database are you using (ESRI or other)? Might not be a bad idea to see how the coordinates are saved in the database to check if the error message is correct.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either, and even googling yields no result. Deducing from the error message I'd say it could be a problem with a geometry which sits outside the defined bounds of your coordinate system, but all I get is a warning: conflict between map and output. I would take this to ESRI if I were you, especially as there is no online source at all (not even one from ESRI!) which references your error.

Comment: Does the SQL-Server table use the GEOGRAPHY datatype? The error may be generated by the database.

Comment: Thanks all, I tried to regenerate the feature class with the same coordinate system, this error not appear. Is the old feature layer "corrupt"?

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error and I can't figure why.
I noticed that this happens only when attempting to make a *geodesic* buffer on *polyline* or *polygon* (but not on point) features with a *non-earth* geographic coordinate system. I still can't figure why this happens, but I figured out two possible workarounds:

- WORKAROUND #1 (easiest one):

  Use the "Buffer Wizard" tool (Customize > Toolbars > Customize... > Commands > search for "Buffer Wizard") instead of the ArcToolbox Buffer tool. This tool does not return the error.
- WORKAROUND #2 (useful just for polylines):

  1) Densify your polyline vertices (i.e. System Toolboxes > Editing Tools > Densify);

  2) Convert your polyline features to *point features*;

  3) Use the Buffer tool (i.e. System Toolboxes > Analysis Tools > Proximity > Buffer) setting *Method = GEODESIC* AND *Dissolve type = ALL*.

However, I hope that an actual solution to this problem comes out sooner or later.